# How can I delete originals in Capture One from within an album (without going back to "all photos")?

Tags: file-management, delete, capture-one

In Capture One if you want to organize your photos inside of a catalog you have to use albums. But if you want to delete an image and you are viewing it in an album the image is only deleted from the album, but remains in the catalog. Which means that to delete the original you have to look it up in the "all photos" collection, which defeats the purpose of organizing photos.

So is there a way to delete the original photo while browsing it in an album?

Answer (score 2):

#### A small technicality

> In Capture One if you want to organize your photos inside of a catalog you have to use albums.

That depends. You could also just use folders on your hard drive - I, for one, create a folder for every day (named `<yyyy>-<mm>-<dd> (<TITLE>)`. Or, if it is a project that spans multiple days, it gets a main folder with the project name and then the subfolders will be named per day. *However, that is not a solution to the problem at hand.*

---

#### Solution

**Note:** I tried these things with Capture One 11 + 12. I think these options were available at least since version 10, however, I have no way to test that.

When you have selected the image(s) to delete, go to the `File` menu (`Image` since v12)<sup>Thanks to [@GerhardBurger](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/79521/gerhard-burger) for spotting this!</sup> and select `Move to catalog trash` or `Delete from Disk`. The latter option obviously deletes the file completely <sup>(**Attention: Capture One does not use the OS's Recycle Bin!**)</sup>, while `Move to catalog trash` moves the file(s) into Capture One's Trash-folder (they still remain in their folders on the HDD, though). Right-click on that (or any folder or collection) and select `Empty Catalog Trash`. Now, a dialog will appear that lets you choose whether do delete the file(s) completely or just delete it/them from the catalog.

It should also be possible to edit the Keyboard Shortcuts (`Edit` - `Keyboard Shortcuts...` so that <kbd>Del</kbd> or some other key can be programmed to move the files to trash instead of just deleting the file(s) from your album.

Comment: In Capture One the options are now in the `Image` menu

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you ask Phase one direct via their user help, which as a paid licence holder you will get a very quick responce

Comment: Well… I'm just using a trial version to understand if I want to buy the thing. But maybe asking directly really makes sense

Comment: While good advice in general, I still think this should be a comment, not an answer (as it isn't one).

Answer (score 0):

If it's with a Mac, right-click over the image in the Browser of Capture One, then click on View in the Finder and delete it there.

Comment: Works with Windows as well (`View in Explorer`, I think)

Answer (score 0):

Best I could find is select the image, then click "image">"delete from disk".

I was hoping to find there's a way to customize the right+click options to include it there, but I guess not.